# Correct preposition for "Disappear"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrasal-verbs, phrase-choice

Are following sentences correct?

> 1- Where all those stuff have disappeared **"*to*"**?

> 2- Where all those stuff have disappeared **"*into*"**?

In dictionaries for **disappear** I see **into** as a preposition but I'm not sure it can be used in above contexts.

Comment: To me, it's correct. In you example, 'where' is an interrogative pronoun and 'to' and 'into' are a preposition.

Comment: I believe it's "that stuff" because it's uncountable

Comment: [Where has all that stuff disappeared to? Please first try to learn how to pose a question properly. Where + verb + subject + past participle + preposition. Please correct your questions.] stuff is singular, and it's that stuff, not this stuff.

Comment: disappear into the house, disappear on the river, disappear in the flames, and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original**

> Where all those stuff have disappeared to?

The usage of **those** and **have** is incorrect because **stuff** is singular ([uncountable](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/countable-and-uncountable-nouns/#:%7E:text=Uncountable%20nouns%20are%20for%20the,used%20with%20a%20singular%20verb.)). Change them to **that** and **has**. (Or change **stuff** to **things**).

> Where all that stuff has disappeared to?

The order sounds awkward (the helping verb **has** should come after the prepositional phrase **to where** but before the noun **stuff**).

**Correct**

> Where has all that stuff disappeared to?

---

I would not consider **to** and **into** to be equivalent in this specific case.

**Into** usually indicates that the destination can be described as the inside of something. **To** indicates a more generic destination.

> Which jar did those coins disappear into?

> Where did those coins disappear to?

Comment: The entire sentence is ungrammatical. I'd fix that first. And leaving a preposition at the end without an object is completely grammatical in spoken English.

Comment: You are correct. I was taught that dangling prepositions were incorrect, but it seems that's a matter of style.

Comment: No, it is not: Where did he disappear to? is completely grammatical and idiomatic. If one expects a place: He disappeared to do his work, to the kitchen, it is perfectly acceptable. In fact, not using it is a native speaker flag.....the expectation is something like: to work (a verb) or to the kitchen (a place). In fact, it is not considered a dangling preposition when speaking. Your dangling preposition thing is for writing.